# How to list files within date range at cli

Tags: linux, files, timestamps

Can one pls tell a proper to list files within date range on cli. Say between Feb 20 to Mar 2 then mv these files to another dir.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For `find` implementations that does not have `-newerct` (older GNU `find` and `find` on BSD systems):

Create two timestamp files and use `find` to find all files that are newer than the oldest of these and older than the newest:

```
touch -d 2018-02-20T00:00:00 ts-start
touch -d 2018-03-03T00:00:00 ts-end

find . -type f -newer ts-start ! -newer ts-end ! -name ts-end -exec mv {} /destination ';'

rm -f ts-start ts-end
```

We have to exclude the `ts-end` filename as that file fulfills the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -newerct "20 Feb 2018" ! -newerct "2 Mar 2018" -exec mv {} /path/to/target/dir
```

This uses features introduced in recent versions of GNU find.

There are plenty of other ways to accomplish the same thing with `find`. See the `man` page for information about `-newerxy`, `-mtime`
and other goodies.